# Loading texts with shapefile in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, overlay, text

I am currently trying to load different shapefiles in ArcObjects programmatically.  Currently I can load lines, polylines, polygons and ellipses (even though that's just a fancy polygon as far as ArcObjects is concerned).

However, I'm having a problem loading texts. Basically it's a point on a map with some text above it.

This is how I'm trying to load the shapefile. Note this is basically the same thing I do for polygons, polylines and ellipses. The only notable difference is ITextSymbol as opposed to ISimpleFillSymbol for Polygons or ISimpleLineSymbol for lines:

```
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayerrClass();
featureLayer.FeatureClass = myFeatureClass //Loaded from the featureWorkspace
featureLayer.Name = featureClass.AliasName;
featureLayer.Visibile = true;

IGeoFeatureLayer layer = featureLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;

IRgbColor textColor = new RgbColorClass();
textColor.Red = 255;
textColor.Blue = 0;
textColor.Green =0;

ITextSymbol textSymbol = new TextSymbolClass();
textSymbol.Color = textColor;
textSymbol.Font = (stdole.IFontDisp)OLE.GetIFontDispFromFont(new Font("Arial", 12 , FontStyle.Bold);
textSymbol.Size = 12;
textSymbol.Text = myText;

ISimpleRenderer simpleRenderer = new SimpleRendererClass();
simpleRenderer.Symbol = textSymbol as ISymbol;
geoFeatureLayer.Renderer = simpleRenderer;

myAxMap.AddLayer(geoFeatureLayer as ILayer);
Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text symbols cannot be used as renderer symbols. You will need to set up labeling for your layer instead.

A good start for setting layer's labeling properties is [IGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/00120000052v000000.htm).

Comment: I do labeling already with other shape files that have labels i.e rivers/lakes/ and just use the ILabelEngineLayerProperties and IAnnotateLayerProperties so I guess it's the same logic

Comment: That being said, should I be using IPoint as my shape?  Or is there a better ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry that I should be using.

It was straight forward with Polygon/Polyline/Ellipse

Comment: But I guess you did not display any text for the polygon/polyline/ellipse cases, did you? Points are the obvious choice for text labels, but once you get into labeling, you can pretty much place the labels on top of anything (be it point, line or polygon).